# What is the best way to ensure there is only a single ORM model instance tied to a row in a database?

Tags: c#, database, orm, hierarchy, object-relational-model

**The Problem**

We have an app that stores hierarchical data in a database. We have defined a POCO object which represents a row of data.

The problem is we need certain properties to be dependent on the item's children and others on their ancestors.  As an example, if a ((great)grand)child has incomplete state, then implicitly all of its parents are also incomplete.  Similarly, if a parent has a status of disabled, then all children should be implicitly disabled as well.

On the database side of things, everything works thanks to triggers. However, the issue we're having is then synching those changes to any in-memory ORM objects that may have been affected.

That's why we're thinking to do all of this, we need to ensure there is only ever one model instance in memory for any specific row in the database.  That's the crux of the entire problem.

We're currently doing that with triggers in the DB, and one giant hash-set of weak references to the objects keyed on the database's ID for the in-memory ORM objects, but we're not sure that's the proper way to go.

**Initial Design**

Our 'rookie' design started by loading all objects from the database which quickly blew out the memory, let alone took a lot of time loading data that may never actually be displayed in the UI as the user may never navigate to it.

**Attempt 2**

Our next attempt expanded on the former by dynamically loading only the levels needed for actual display in the UI, which greatly sped up loading, but now doesn't allow the state of the hierarchy to be polled without several calls to the database.

**Attempt 2B**

Similar to above, but we added persistent 'implicit status' fields which were updated via triggers in the database.  That way if a parent was disabled, a trigger updated all children accordingly. Then the model objects simply refreshed themselves with the latest values from the database.  This has the down-side of putting some business logic in the model layer and some in the database triggers as well as making both database writes and reads needed for every operation.

**Fully Dynamic**

This time we tried to make our models 'dumb' and removed our business layer completely from the code, moving that logic entirely to the database.  That way there was only single-ownership of the business rules. Plus, this guaranteed bad data couldn't be inserted into the database in the first place. However, here too we needed to constantly poll the database for the 'current' values, meaning some logic did have to be built in to know which objects needed to be refreshed.

**Fully Dynamic with Metadata**

Similar to above, but all write calls to the database returned an update token that told the models if they had to refresh any loaded parents or children.

I'm hoping to get some feedback from the SO community on how to solve this issue.

Comment: is there a reason why the database was not `normalized` so that it can handle relational aspect ? just curious.. because it's hard to picture what the database current structure is without seeing a data-model etc..

Comment: It's already normalized.  For simplicity's sake, consider three columns... ID, ParentID (Nullable) and Name.  The problem isn't the database.  It's the ORM side of things with the status needing to be updated both up and down the hierarchy since there are visual status indicators in the UI.

Comment: is this a problem with how the data is being joined and or retrieved based on foreign keys and or Inner / outer joins..? would like to see some examples of what the issue and hurdles are

Comment: Again, the database is fine.  Items are retrieved appropriately from a SQL perspective. If this was simply dumping SQL results to the screen, there wouldn't be any issues.  The problem however is around keeping the ORM objects synchronized with what's in the database. In other words, if I mark a parent as disabled, all children are thusly implicitly disabled.  They're marked as disabled in the database thanks to triggers, but the models representing the children all also need to be refreshed, and they may only be partially loaded, etc.  Does that make sense? Again, it's not a DB issue.

Comment: Ok so the triggers are fine.. correct..? there has to be some cascading issue that can be fixed or check the cascading updates incorrectly if I understand what you are saying.. if the database is fine then the problem lies within the ORM side

Comment: Exactly.  The DB side of things is fine, but trying to keep the already-loaded-in-memory ORM objects in sync with the rows in the database that changed because of triggers is where we're being tripped up.  Only thing I can think of is with every update that would fire triggers, have those triggers also update a temp table with affected IDs, then return those IDs to the UI, which would then see if any of those IDs are loaded, and refresh them accordingly, which again is why I need to ensure only one ORM object exists per row.

Comment: Unless this entire approach is misguided and there's a better way to do this. I'm actually not fond of the 'triggers' approach because now the business logic is storage-dependent, but to do it purely in the business layer, all objects would have to be loaded in memory, which kills performance.  That's why I'm stumped on this.

Comment: How is this different with situation when some row is just updated in database and you need to refresh your state at client? I mean that it seems not to be specific for cascading updates. Why not use regular cache? How do you handle regular updates now in UI? I mean how do you know if _anything_ has changed - polling?

Comment: I forgot to add... single client user for a local SQLite database so there won't be any updates to the DB without the UI knowing about it... with the exception of triggers updating the data.  In that case the DB will know about it but how will that get reported back to the UI?

Comment: ORMs are indeed a misguided approach. Rows in a database represent propositions, not entities, and OOP is meant for decomposing computational systems into collaborating components, not for modeling data.

Comment: While I respect (albeit disagree) with that stance (to me a DB is just the storage-representation of the in-memory objects), do you have a better approach?  Again, we have tens of thousands of rows of hierarchical data which we don't want to load into memory, but some of our screens show multiple levels of that hierarchy simultaneously (think 'Miller' columns, like in macOS.)  Again, a change in one level affects *all* other levels, which db triggers handle, but I'm trying to address the already-loaded-in-memory objects. Since you disagree, how would you solve it?